# Is there way to get Development/Distribution/APN certificate without p12 file

Tags: ios, certificate

I know that we can get this certificates using P12,
But is it possible to get certificate without p12 file.

I have Developer Account credential, But not able to contact older developer who has created Certificate.
So i have to create new certificate or is it possible to get certificate without P12 files?

Comment: You can create new certificates from developer account.

Comment: Yes, but i want my older certificates, Is there way?

Comment: No, and as you can imagine if it was possible this would be a huge security issue.

Comment: How can it be Risk, as no one knows my Credential, With credential anyone can do far more harm other than Certificate.